# hierarchical Max in LAMBDA OR LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a build version list

```
List<int[]> BuildVersions;
```

How can i find last build version.

Build Versions such as

```
100.1.2.3
101.12.3.2
101.12.3.3
```

**Update**: the expression must check first number then second one,then third one ,then last one

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's pretty hard to determine what you mean at the moment.

Comment: What are you mean under "last build version". What structure "version" has? Provide some sample daata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int[] maxVersion = buildVersions.OrderByDescending(v => v[0])
                                .ThenByDescending(v => v[1])
                                .ThenByDescending(v => v[2])
                                .FirstOrDefault();
```

OR a more generic solution is as under

```
T[] HierarchicalMax<T>(IEnumerable<T[]> items)
        {
            var length = items.Min(v => v.Length);
            IEnumerable<T[]> result = items;

            for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            {
                int offset = i;
                result = result.OrderByDescending(v => v[offset]);
            }

            T[] max = result.FirstOrDefault();

            return max;
        }
```

Comment: That's it.Great bro.The second one is really great.Thanks

Comment: Why not just do `for (int offset = 0; offset < length; offset++)`?

Comment: This doesn't work if you have versions of different lengths. For example with [2.1.1, 2.1.2, 1.2] it might select 2.1.1.

Comment: i is not part of closure for that a local variable is required

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of arrays of ints, and you want to determine the highest int in there somewhere.

That would be something like this:

```
var max = BuildVersions.Max(x => x.Max(y => y));
```

Comment: No maybe it is not.The expression must check first number and then second and then third and then the last one.

Comment: That's what this does. It takes the Max out of the list of values which are already Maxes of the arrays.

Comment: It takes the max number of the single version (10.12.11.9 will return 12) and then sorts by that, that won't work.

Comment: Sorts by that? I don't see it sort. How does it sort?

Comment: Aha, I see the question was modified now... It's a totally different thing than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

A little inefficient as it finds the minimum length of the current set of filtered versions each time. The time of this could be traded for space at the additional cost of complicating the code. It assumes 1.1 is greater than 1.1.1.

```
for (int versionPart = 0; versionPart < versions.Min(v => v.Length); versionPart += 1) {
    versions = versions.MaxValues(version => version[versionPart]);
}
var maxVersion = versions.FirstOrDefault();
```

With the extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MaxItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, int> selector) {  
    var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator();  

    if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) {  
        return Enumerable.Empty<T>();  
    }  

    var maxItem = enumerator.Current;  
    List<T> maxItems = new List<T>() { maxItem };  
    int maxValue = selector(maxItem);  

    while (enumerator.MoveNext()) {  
        var item = enumerator.Current;  
        var value = selector(item);  

        if (value > maxValue) {  
            maxValue = value;  
            maxItems = new List<T>() { item };  
        } else if (value == maxValue) {  
            maxItems.Add(item);  
        }  
    }  

    return maxItems;  
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you a list of int array?

If not,

```
int maxValue=BuildVersions.Max();
```

Comment: He has a list of int array, what ever it is (only because the answer doesn't work) -1